# Laravel many to many query filter on array

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent

I have the follow code

```
$apartments->whereHas('options',function ($query) use($options){
            $query->whereIn('nome',$options);
        });
```

In a filter page this return all the apartments that have one or all options in the options array.
I want return just the apartments that have only the select options.
Explain better:for example I have options pool and tv-sat if I use my code te result is to return  the apartments that have both options(and this is ok) but also the apartments that match only a conditions(and I don't want this).
Please help me and sorry for my english.

Comment: In the query builder, there may be no option for such kind of situation. But you can use the laravel collection method to filter the apartments after getting the above results.

Comment: If each apartment can only have each option once, then you might be able to add an extra havingRaw Clause to your query to make sure the number of options the apartment has matches the number of options in $options.

Comment: Tried `function ($query) use ($option) {$query->where(['nome' => $option]);}`?